# Backup and Sync from Linux to a WSL live (per each change)

Tags: backup, synchronization, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hosting-services

I have a Linux (Arch/Debian) with only a CLUI (Bash) and a server environment (LAMP) with the following details:

```
4 GB RAM
2 vCPU Cores
80 GB SSD 
4 TB Transfer
40 Gbps Network In
4000 Mbps Network Out
```

I host two websites (WordPress and/or Drupal) on each system.

I want to backup and sync such a system live to my Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) but I don't want hourly/daily/weekly cron; I want that **every change in scope** of my system would be synced to a directory in my WSL.

What I desire is very much like Google's *Backup&Sync* which I use in my Windows 10 / Ubuntu machines to prevent data loss in case a computer was unexpectedly and sadly ruined or stolen and formatted (in contrast to manual deletion of data after it was stolen where the data would be lost even in the remote syncing environment).

My question is how to do such live syncing (like Google's *Backup&Sync*) from Linux to WSL?

---

### Side note

This is how I backup manually so far and it's exactlly the process I desire to automate:

```
 cib() {
    # Create an Immediate ZIP Backup (of both $drt and DB);
    date="$(date \+%F\-%T)"
    mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip "$drt/db-$date.zip" - # Note the hyphen before this comment;
    zip -r "${drt}/all_zipped-$date.zip" "$drt"/ -x "*/cache/*" "*/phpmyadmin/*"
    rm -f "$drt/db-$date.zip"
```

Comment: You have to look into inotify-tools and probably write some custom service that will sync your files on update, remove filesystem events, than you have to think of mechanism that would compare files and decide on which files to sync. Its a bit complicated to do it, you can write a custom script but it will have limitef functionality, you probably have to right a custom program for example in golang.

Comment: Extending Andruis' comment, it is not so hard. You need mainly simple scripting. However, backup is *much* better if you don't do it realtime - consider an accidental data deletion, your backup system will also replicate the mistake on the backup instances on the spot. Backup should happen periodically and automatically, but *not* in realtime (except if you have also some versioning on the backend).